Why was my question about the name "Jakin" (Croatian name for Ancona) poorly received? Are questions about toponyms generally poorly received?
I am talking about this question: Why is the Croatian name for Ancona "Jakin", rather than something like *Jukin?
My similar question about the phonological development of the word "vjetar" (wind) was well-received: Why is the Croatian word "vjetar" spelt with "je" rather than "e"?
My similar question about the phonological development of the word "pjena" (foam) was received relatively well: Why is the Croatian word "pjena" (foam) spelt with "je" as if it were from Slavic yat, rather than "i", as it is from Slavic "y"?
Are the questions about toponyms generally poorly received on this forum?

I don't think the fact the first is about toponyms is a factor.
The two factors I see as likely more significant is that the first question was submitted 3 years after the others. There is generally no guarantee that a community that appreciates one type of question at one point in time will appreciate the same type of question 3 years later. Tastes change, and so a question that is received well one year might be received poorly if asked a few years later.
The other, and probably more significant factor, is that the first question is about loanword adaptation, whilst the others are about the evolution within a specific language.
Whilst loanword adaptation is often reasonably systematic, exceptions are more common than they are in direct linguistic descent and so questions about it are harder to answer.
